# Problems with kio sftp in Dolphin/Konqueror

Tags: ssh, kubuntu, kde, dolphin

I'm running Kubuntu 15.04 and having problems connecting via the kio slave for SFTP.  I can access the remote server via ssh and the command line but not through dolphin/konqueror via SFTP.  I receive a notification "The host key for this server was not found, but another type of key exists."  Will attach screenshot for this.
I see a bug was filed in KDE's Bugzilla with a status of resolved: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=274170 in reards to this but having what looks like to be the same problem.

Any ideas on what to do?

Comment: Couldn't figure out how to attach a screenshot but here is the full text "The host key for this server was not found, but another type of key exists.  An attacker might change the default server key to confuse your client into thinking the key does not exist.  Pleas contact your system administrator"

Answer (score 11):

This is a known issue with Dolphin and ECDSA keys. OpenSSH in recent versions have moved to use ECDSA by default over RSA, and this works fine with most implementations that rely on OpenSSH's "known hosts" file.

Dolphin's kio_sftp module uses libssh instead of OpenSSH's own libraries, and that library appears to not support ECDSA keys. The workaround is detailed in the KDE bug report - remove the existing key, and either force OpenSSH to cache the RSA host key (an example command line is detailed in the bug report and below), or just use Dolphin to connect directly.

Because the KDE bug is resolved, but we still see the bug in Kubuntu 15.04, I've opened a bug on the [Kubuntu KDE implementation](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kde-runtime/+bug/1450085).

Sample command to reset the host key:

```
ssh-keygen -f "$HOME/.ssh/known_hosts" -R server
ssh -o HostKeyAlgorithms=ssh-rsa user@server
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this.  It solved my issues just hadn't got a chance to test it.  Marked it as a solution

Comment: Yes, the commands helped. FYI: it's not marked as a solution.

Comment: Its not a solution, its a workaround ;-) but yea, @jjesse: if you this is worth accepting as an answer, please click the checkmark. Thx.

Answer (score 5):

As workaround you can use **fish**://yourserver instead of sftp and it'll work just great. Solution was taken from there: https://superuser.com/questions/299940/kubuntu-cant-add-new-ssh-network-folder